# How to configure postgres sql URL in JDBC using spring.xml

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc

We are using Spring mvc for our project. In Spring.xml we want to use our newly migrated postgres db. But we are not being able to configure the url.

```
<bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
<property name="dataSource" ref="ds"></property>
</bean>
```

This gives us an error: [err]

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Invalid sslmode value: verify-full;sslrootcert=/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/resources/iitStaticContent/root.crt
[err]   at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
[err]   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:390)
```

Comment: try reading the error message `Invalid sslmode value: verify-full`

Comment: but as far as i understand sslmode=verify-full is a valid option.

Comment: Maybe it is what comes next - the format is `jdbc:postgresql://<instance_ip>:<instance_port>/<database_name>?sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=<ca.pem>`

Answer (score 2):

You use an ampersand (`&`), not a semicolon (`;`), to separate options in an URL.

You may need to encode that as `&amp;` in XML.

Comment: Whenever i use an '&' i am getting a compilation error in eclipse saying

Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Start tag of element <property>
 - The reference to entity "sslcert" must end with the ';' 
  delimiter.
 - End tag of element <property>

Comment: Try encoding it, as suggested in my extended answer.